# What is Threat Profile is Microsoft addressing with the MSAL URI format?

Tags: authentication, openid-connect, microsoft, openid, authenticator

Applications built for MSAL 1.0 and MSAL 2.0 have a default application URI of `MSAL://GUIDHere/AppName`

This is in contrast with what other IDP's are doing.

Can anyone explain the benefits or drawbacks of this format? (sometimes a "feature" might be called a security "bug")

Comment: What are other IDP's doing? How does it differ from what Microsoft is doing?